# PHPunit stopped working on MAMP

Tags: php, phpunit, mamp

I´ve been trying to run through the [Netbeans PHPunit tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/phpunit.html).
I got PHPunit up and working yesterday but now i´m getting this error when running the test:

```
ReflectionException: Class PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase does not exist in     /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/PHPUnit/Util/Test.php on line 417`
```

xdebug is installed and works.

### My setup:

Mac OS X Lion 10.7 (11A511)
Mamp Pro 2.0.3

`which php`

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php
```

`which pear`

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/pear
```

`which phpunit`

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/phpunit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your phpunit / version / installation the DB-Unit package might not be included in the standard distribution.

Use `pear install phpunit/DbUnit` to get that package